# Последний элемент массива в js

Tags: javascript

Почему в данном коде последний элемент массива который передан функции  inArray( [1,2,3,4,5] ) не добавляется в массив  result ? Но если в конец массива добавить любой другой элемент то результат будет правильным  ( result = [ 3,4,5] ).

```
function inArray(array) {
    return function (currentArray) {
        var result = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < currentArray.length; ++i) {     
            if (currentArray[i] in array )
                result.push(currentArray[i]);
       } 
       return result ;
    }
}
var a = inArray([1,2,3,4,5])([3,5,4]); // result = 3,4
alert(a);
```

Comment: Igor по сути ответил, а вообще, вам просто "повезло", что вы взяли маленькие числа, отвечая на вторую часть вопроса: у вас частично все сработало лишь потому, что в массиве `[1,2,3,4,5]` есть элементы с индексами 3, 4 отсюда и отсутствие 5 (так как последний индекс - 4).

Answer (score 2):

Потому что Вы перепутали оператор `in` и функцию `indexOf/includes`.

> Но если в конец массива добавить ...

*(В коде два массива. О каком из них речь? Очевидно, о первом.)*

Потому что тогда в `array` появляется элемент с индексом `5`.

```js
function inArray(array) {
    return function (currentArray) {
        var result = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < currentArray.length; ++i) {     
            if (array.includes(currentArray[i]))
                result.push(currentArray[i]);
       } 
       return result ;
    }
}
var a = inArray([1,2,3,4,5])([3,5,4]); // result = 3,4
console.log(a);
```